# How to reload a component in reacts on url parameter change?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have the following route:-

```
ReactDOM.render((
     <Router history={browserHistory}>
      <Route path="/" component={app}>
        <IndexRoute component={home}/>
        <Route path="/articles" component={articles} />
        <Route path="/articles/topics/:featureName" component={filteredArticles} />
      </Route>
    </Router>
), document.getElementById('app'));
```

Now when i request for /articles/topics/topic1, the first 5 contents are fetched are using API call. When user reaches the bottom of the page again an API call is made where next 5 contents are fetched. This is working fine(Notice that the handlescroll function checks for the page bottom, which has few minor issues so commented that out for now.)

Now say I choose next topic from the list so the url changes, so my url changes to /articles/topics/topic2 , now i need the same thing as mentioned above and call apis for this topic.

Following is my current component code:-

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import ArticleList from './ArticleList';
import Banner from './Banner';
import LeftNavBar from './LeftNavBar';
import RightNavbar from './RightNavbar';
import {url} from './Constants';


/*MERGE INTO ARTICLES ONCE SCROLL LOGIC IS FIXED*/
class FilteredArticles extends React.Component{

  constructor(){
    super();
    {/* Adding global event listener,binding it to scroll event and adding it to handleScroll function */}
    /*window.addEventListener("scroll", this._handleScroll.bind(this));*/
    this.state ={
      articles : [],
      loadingFlag:false,
      limit : 5,
      offset :0,
      subFeatureName:[],
      flag: false
    }
  }


  _getContent(){
    let self=this;
    axios.get(url+'/articles/filter/?filter=popular&category='+this.props.params.featureName+'&limit='+this.state.limit+'&offset='+this.state.offset)
    .then(function(response){
        /*Checking if limit has exceeded meta count, if it has stopped we dont call the APIS*/
        if(self.state.limit  >= response.data.meta.total_count){
          self.setState({articles : self.state.articles.concat(response.data.results),
              offset : self.state.limit,
              limit: self.state.limit+self.state.offset,
              subFeatureName: self.props.params.featureName,
              loadingFlag: false}
        )
      }
        else{
          self.setState({articles : self.state.articles.concat(response.data.results),
              offset : self.state.limit,
              limit: self.state.limit+self.state.offset,
              subFeatureName: self.props.params.featureName,
              loadingFlag: true}
            )
        }
    })
    .catch(function(error){
       console.log(error);
    });
  }



  _handleScroll(){
    /*Calling 5 more articles when someone scrolls down and reaches the page end
    const windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
    const scrollT = $(window).scrollTop();
    if(windowHeight- scrollT < 200){
      if(!this.state.loadingFlag){
        this.setState({loadingFlag : true});
        this._getContent();
      }
  }*/
}

  componentDidMount(){
    /*calling _getContent function to get first five articles on page load*/
    console.log("got content");
    this._getContent();
  }

   render(){
     console.log("inside render");
     return(
       <div>
         <Banner title="Article Page"/>
         <div className="content-container">
           <LeftNavBar/>
           <div className ="feeds">
             <div className="card">
               {/* Sending hideSeeAll as prop to remove see all button on main article page*/}
                <ArticleList articles={this.state.articles} hideSeeAll='true' keyword="Top Articles"/>
             </div>
           </div>
           <RightNavbar/>
         </div>
      </div>
   )
 }
}

export default FilteredArticles;
```

So basically I am trying to understand that if I have a route like **/articles/topics/:featureName** and I call a page like /articles/topics/topic1 or /articles/topics/topic2, can the component be realoaded(I need to call different API are fetch content once again).

That is, for /articles/topics/topic1 the API called is

**/api/v0/articles/filter/?filter=popular&category=topic1&limit=5&offset=0**

and for /articles/topics/topic2 the API called is

**/api/v0/articles/filter/?filter=popular&category=topic2&limit=5&offset=0**

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You shouldn't really be querying the API/updating the components state in this fashion but hey that's another question entirely. Maybe consider using a [Flux](https://facebook.github.io/flux/) approach.

Anyhow, you can use the **componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps)** life cycle method to receive the routers nextProps params and query your API again:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    this._getContent(nextProps.params.featureName);
}

_getContent(featureName) {
 ...query your API
}
```

Comment: I tried this :-

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
    console.log("here");
    console.log("props"+nextProps.params.featureName);
    this.setState({
      articles : [],
      loadingFlag:false,
      limit : 5,
      offset :0,
      subFeatureName:[],
      flag: false
    });
    console.log("after receive"+JSON.stringify(this.state));
    this._getContent(nextProps.params.featureName);
  }

but the state is not getting updated when i tried printing after calling setState

Comment: setState() does not immediately mutate this.state but creates a pending state transition. Accessing this.state after calling this method can potentially return the existing value.

Comment: then how should I use this? its using old data to call the API

Comment: It appears that calling this.setState() within componentWillReceiveProps (or on resolution of your API promise in your case) will not trigger an additional render. You are using react-router so I assume your application will be a fair size? In which case I would recommend that you look at a state container such as Redux to resolve your apps architectural problems: http://redux.js.org/

Comment: upvoted for redux, i was planning to use redux in the next release. So currently i have 5 topics under an article, I think creating separate routes for each category is better option than spending time on debugging this.

Comment: Sounds like the best approach if you are going to be using redux. good luck with your app

Answer (score 2):

Also, if you're using Redux, make a check like this to avoid an infinite loop:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) {
    if (this.props.someValue === newProps.someValue) {
        this.props.fetchSomething(newProps.params.somethingName);
    }
}
```

Comment: should maybe be `this.props.someValue !== newProps.someValue`, with the ! ...?